# Why couldn't Krall and crew repair the USS Franklin when Scotty and Jaylah could?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Why couldn't Krall and crew repair the USS Franklin when Scotty and Jaylah could?

Jaylah is not Starfleet (yet) but was still able to work on USS Franklin, and was eventually able to get it running with the help of Scotty.

Why didn't Krall do that instead, using surviving crew members and/or drone workers, instead of choosing the more extreme option...

Krall, being a Starfleet captain of the ship, should have known more about the USS Fraklin than Jaylah or Scotty ever could in the limited time at the crash site, right?

Comment: What makes you think star fleet captains, let alone an ex marine/maco turned captain, would know anything about advanced warp engineering and repair?

Comment: In both continuities, Scotty is shown to be a cut above most Starfleet engineers, and way above most captains when it comes to engineering.

Comment: Was it mentioned how many crew members survived the crash? The ship didn't appear to be too damaged, but maybe that's because Jaylah had been working on it for years(?).

Comment: How long ago did the Franklin crash? It's possible that training for repairing star ships is just much more wide-spread and better than when the Franklin lifted off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are actually several points for why he didn't fix it.

First of all, he was one of the very first Starfleet captains, and he was a *military* major before being captain, so he probably knew nothing about warp engineering.

Second, not many crew members survived. Who knows how many of them had useful knowledge (if any) in this situation?

Here's why Jaylah could:

I think it's pretty obvious that the girl is a genius, and she worked on the U.S.S Franklin for years. Meanwhile, Krall went mad.

And she had the help of no one else but Scotty.